# seam with matcap and modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers

why cube-2 has such a seam at a certain viewing angle .. But cube-3 does not have
[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N6wvPqvsaxkRuEeHDz_sJ63XXeJE7CtZ/view?usp=share_link)
[image]

Comment: You have some problems here, like overlapping faces, or faces that go beyond the mirror axis... the first thing is to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@moonboots is on it.. you have an internal overlap.. *Mirror* reflects both ways.

If you jiggle one of the suspect faces before the *Mirror* is applied (Here, with  'Edit Cage' switched on at the top of the modifiers) you can see the overlap:

[image]

Or, after the *Mirror* is applied:

[image]

One way to prevent this would be to cut one side or the the other off with the 'Bisect' setting:

[image]

Comment: cube-2 does not have a mirror modifier. Where does this defect come from, how to fix it?

Comment: is it possible to see this internal overlap? Is this something theoretical or can be seen it? In x-ray mode or something else. Is this a problem with the length of the edges?
The illustration is very important and useful for beginners.

Comment: Hi @blenduser, does this edit help? If you see something suspect in shading, or have odd behaviour in Edit Mode, (things like loop-cuts not going all the way round where they should,) jiggling vertices and faces around, or H hiding them for a while, is one of the first moves to look for faults.  With less overpowering matcaps, you can sometimes see the Z-fighting, too .. the hazy diagonals where there are two faces fighting to be 'in front'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will study based on your tips and illustrations.
Even in orthography x-ray, it is noticeable that there are some extra faces in the cube2 object - compared to cube-3